# YouTube API Upload Video as 'Unlisted' or 'Private'?

Tags: api, upload, youtube

I am using a Wordpress plugin called 'YouTube Uploader', it allows you to upload YouTube videos from your WordPress site, it is working for me but the only issue is that it uploads the videos as Public and I need them to go up as Unlisted or Private (either will do). If someone could tell me what to add/change to make it do this, it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I uploaded the code to Pastebin as I didn't want to fill this entire post with code, heres the link: http://pastebin.com/GfQjhiiq

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that clued up on Wordpress but what you're looking for is a tag called [`<yt:private/>`](http://code.google.com/intl/no/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3aprivate)

`<yt:private/>` is a child of **media:group** so a sample xml schema could look something like the following.  (Note where `<yt:private/>` sits within the code block):

```
<media:group>
   <media:title type="plain">Title here</media:title>
   <media:description type="plain">Description here</media:description>
   <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Travel</media:category>
   <media:keywords>keyword1</media:keywords>
   <yt:private/>
</media:group>
```

Hope this is of some use.

Comment: You have an extraneous '</cfoutput>' in your xml

Comment: Also, the category has to be a valid existing youtube category e.g. 'Travel'

Comment: @Danack57 - have amended your observations - thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 3):

I think this method is pretty outdated. But there is a work around if you were to use the the Plain PHP API method...

**This Part does the trick:**

```
// unlisted upload
    $accessControlElement = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element('yt:accessControl', 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', '');
    $accessControlElement->extensionAttributes = array(
        array(
        'namespaceUri' => '',
        'name' => 'action',
        'value' => 'list'
        ),
        array(
        'namespaceUri' => '',
        'name' => 'permission',
        'value' => 'denied'
        ));
    $myVideoEntry->extensionElements = array($accessControlElement);
```

**In the bigger scheme:**

```
    $this->Zend->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    $this->Zend->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');

    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(ZEND_GDATA_CLIENT_EMAIL, ZEND_GDATA_CLIENT_PASS, 'youtube');
    $client->setHeaders('X-GData-Key', "key=".ZEND_GDATA_YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY);
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($client);
    $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

    // unlisted upload
    $accessControlElement = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element(
            'yt:accessControl', 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', ''
    );
    $accessControlElement->extensionAttributes = array(
        array(
        'namespaceUri' => '',
        'name' => 'action',
        'value' => 'list'
        ),
        array(
        'namespaceUri' => '',
        'name' => 'permission',
        'value' => 'denied'
        ));

    $myVideoEntry->extensionElements = array($accessControlElement);

    $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My Test Movie');
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie');
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Sports');
```

**The whole Gist is over here:** https://gist.github.com/1044349